# Regex until repeat character (uri path)

Tags: regex

I've got such examples

```
/path/to/service/People("Peter")
/i/dont/care/about/how/much/pathes/we/have/here/Customer("John")
/itcouldbejustone/Client("Rick")
```

i need to regex and leave just People("Peter"), Customer("John"), Client("Rick") accordingly

i was trying to use:

```
\/.+?(?=\/)
```

but we have a lot of "/" slashes, how to avoid it? thanks

Comment: Which language or tool are you using? Are you using some specific regex library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it greedy ....

```
\/.+(?=\/)
```

To match also the last `/`,

```
\/.+\/
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kQ0iM6/3)

Comment: Use this `\/.+\/` if you want to match also the last `/`

Comment: thanks, but how to include the last slash - just leave People... without .../People?

Comment: this regexp is not working for these example: /check/my/path/Person HTTP/1.1 because it catches the last slash after HTTP but it should do it before Person

Comment: d'u know how to omit that?

Comment: simple `\/.+\/(?=Person)` like `\/.+\/(?=[A-Z])` or `\/.+\/(?=[A-Za-z])`

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without regex if using PHP

```
$url = '/path/to/service/People("Peter")';
$name = end(explode("/", $url));
```

$name will have    `People("Peter");`

Comment: i don't need PHP, i need REGEX pattern

Answer (score 0):

That depends a bit on which regex tool you are using.

Anyway, there are many ways of getting that:

- If you will never have a slash at the final part, you can ask for whatever comes after the last slash:

  ```
  .*\/([^\/]+)
  ```

  Your desired result will be at the group 1.
- If the last part will always have the format `name("string")` then you can match this format as well - which strikes me as more explicit pattern:

  ```
  \w+\(".*"\)
  ```

Comment: what if i will have the slashes after like here: /path/to/Person("jack") HTTP/1.1 ? we've got slash after HTTP but need to be before Person

Comment: @ServerSideCat The second regex should match this case. Hasn't it?